# Is it a good practice to close an SQL connection after catching an Exception?

Tags: c#, exception, resources, sqlconnection

Wondering if I should explicitly close my SQL connection after an error occurs, or if this is done automatically?

Suppose I have some click event

```
string conString = "something";
string query = "someQuery";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, con);
try {
   con.Open()
   //Something that will cause an error
} catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
   MessageBox.Show("Error Occurred")
   con.Close()
}
```

is this a best practice or would this be serving no purpose? The idea would be to retry the operation after closing the message box.

Comment: Check the documentation. You need to include a `using` statement to properly dispose of the connection. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: Is that necessary if `using System.Data.SqlClient;` is already included in the code at the start?

Comment: That's not quite what I'm referring to. Again, please read the documentation.

Comment: `using System.Data.SqlClient` is a using *directive*; a using *statement* is completely different

Comment: It should be `using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString)) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are meant to clean up the connection when you're done regardless of exception or success, but that doesn't necessarily mean calling `Close`. More commonly, you'd just use a `using` statement, which calls a cleanup API (`Dispose()`) when leaving scope. This is very simple:

```cs
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
{
    con.Open();
    //Something
}
```

Or in more recent versions of C#, if the `using` would end at the end of the parent scope:

```cs
using var con = new SqlConnection(conString);
using var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
con.Open();
//Something
```

Comment: I think it is important to note here the difference for OP's example. Using a using statement, the connection will automatically "close" or "dispose" of itself once it's outside of the using statement as in Marcs example.  I.e. an exception..  Using statement IS NOT the same as a using directive!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Finally
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch-finally

```
  try
    {
        //exec
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
       // call error ;
    }
    finally
    {
        // close conn            
    }
```